# How to store user input as a variable with a modal dialog library? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog, alert, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I'm trying to save user input via alert as a variable. I actually can do it via JS using **prompt**, but can't implement a similar solution with **sweetalert** and **sweetalert2** libraries.

I read through their documentation and examples:

https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#advanced-examples
https://sweetalert2.github.io/#input-types

My efforts return **[Object promise]** placeholder instead of variable text in the best case, but usually, it is not working at all:
https://codepen.io/dimos082/pen/xeXmqK

Here's the implementation that works for me in JavaScript with alert pop-ups:
https://codepen.io/dimos082/pen/ROLEpo

```
<html>
<body>
    <button onclick="TellTale()">Tell me a story</button>
    <p id="Tale"></p>  <!-- Result from TellTale() will be put here as innerHTML-->  
</body>
<script> 
    function TellTale() {let KnightName = prompt("How do people call you, oh Noble Knight?");
    document.getElementById("Tale").innerHTML = "Once upon a time, there lived a champion, noble Sir " + KnightName + "."}
</script>
</html>
```

I look for the same variable handling as in the code above.
Is it possible with those 2 libraries, or you can suggest a better solution for replacing standard alerts?

Thank you!

Comment: Please try using a Modal to collect input from user instead of an alert. Please checkout modal tutorial from W3 schools: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

Comment: @ManoshTalukder Thank you very much for your response. Unfortunately there is no information regarding user input collection. Also, I haven't found anything similar on the internet so far. Probably you know other tutorials, will be much appreciated!

Comment: You're welcome. Unfortunately, without knowing what will be coming from users as input, it is difficult to speculate an appropriate solution. What I can suggest is if your project is a simple Single Page Application (SPA), you try using a frontend framework like AngularJS, Angular or React, and can easily bind the user input with your model. Try looking up their references. If you use an appropriate framework to achieve this, you can later convert this into something which can use API calls to manage the story data binding.

Comment: @ManoshTalukder  Thank you again for your reply, basically I use vanilla JS, I believe it should work there. You can see how user's input being handled here just pressing "Tell me a story" button https://codepen.io/dimos082/pen/ROLEpo ; And how I'm trying to do with the sweetalert library (as CDN) https://codepen.io/dimos082/pen/xeXmqK ; I guess I'm missing something in promises.

Comment: Sorry I missed that you were asking for help with the Promises only, so rather than an alternate solution, provided the solution with Promise below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution to this problem:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<html>
<body>
    <button onclick="TellTale()">Tell me a story</button>
    <p id="Tale"></p>  <!-- Result from TellTale() will be put here as innerHTML-->  
</body>
<script> 
function TellTale() {
 swal("How do people call you, oh Noble Knight?", {
   content: "input"
 }).then(KnightName => document.getElementById("Tale").innerHTML = "Once upon a time, there lived a champion, noble Sir " + KnightName + ".")
}
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You handled the Promise incorrectly. Please study the [Promises in ES5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) for references. You assigned a Promise object to your variable, which is async. It went to the next line appended the object itself instead of the value of the Promise, because the value was not resolved then.You need to work with that value when the Promise is resolved using the `.then()` method on the Promise. Here is your modified TellTale method that's working with the Promise:

```
function TellTale() {
     let KnightName = swal("How do people call you, oh Noble Knight?", 
     {
        content: "input",
     }).then(function(value){
           document.getElementById("Tale").innerHTML = "Once upon a 
           time, there lived a champion, noble Sir " + value + ".";
     });
}
```

My explanation might seem a bit complicated, but will clear up when you study a bit about Promises and how to handle stuff on resolve/reject.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Manosh. Unfortunately this piece of code is not working. But I've gone through promises as you asked and came up with with that piece `function TellTale() {
 swal("How do people call you, oh Noble Knight?", {
   content: "input"
 }).then(KnightName => document.getElementById("Tale").innerHTML = "Once upon a time, there lived a champion, noble Sir " + KnightName + ".")
}`

Comment: For some reason when I copy pasted my solution into your codepen, it didn't work, but typing it again seemed to work. Whether you handle the resolved promise with regular function or arrow function (like you did) it will work. Glad to know you got the hold of it. :)

Comment: Thank you, Manosh!